# Change id of elements in ContentPlaceHolder

Tags: asp.net, webforms, contentplaceholder

I use masterpage in asp.net web form, I use span to display message to users

```
<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder2" runat="server">

     <div class="col-md-10 col-sm-10">
         <span id="spnMessage" class="btnText" runat="server"></span>
     </div>

</asp:Content>
```

and code is:

```
spnMessage.InnerText = "Add record successfully ";
```

but in runtime id of span change to "ContentPlaceHolder2_spnMessage" and my code does not work. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Change the `span` into a Literal. Then there will be no more issues with ID conflicts.

```
<asp:Literal ID="spnMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
```

Then accessing the Literal from code behind will always work.

```
spnMessage.Text = "Add record successfully ";
```

Or if you need to use the `<span>` element for CSS purposes, you can still wrap the Literal with it.

```
<span><asp:Literal ID="spnMessage" runat="server"></asp:Literal></span>
```

You could also use a aspnet `Label`.
A label will generate it's own `<div>` tag in HTML.

```
<asp:Label ID="spnMessage" runat="server" Text="Add record successfully"></asp:Label>
```

Will become

```
<div>Add record successfully</div>
```